# hide UIButtons when UITableView is empty

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uibutton

```
  func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        if carts.count > 0 {
            self.tableView.backgroundView = nil
            self.tableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine
            return 1


        }

        let rect = CGRect(x: 0,
                          y: 0,
                          width: self.tableView.bounds.size.width,
                          height: self.tableView.bounds.size.height)
        let noDataLabel: UILabel = UILabel(frame: rect)

        noDataLabel.text = "nothing, the table is empty"
        noDataLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        noDataLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        self.tableView.backgroundView = noDataLabel
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = .none
      self.total.isHidden = true
       self.proceedbtn.isHidden = true
        self.totalLab.isHidden = true


        return 1
    }
```

the code above will hide the objects when the tableView is empty. However, when I add items in it ( it's supposed to be a cart) the `total` `proceedbtn` and `totalLab` are still hidden !!

Is there a way to reload the table and check if it's empty ?

Note :

My cells are slidable and I can delete the cell by sliding.

```
func deleteMail(_ path:IndexPath) {
    guard carts.count > path.row else {
        print("Index out of range")
        return
    }

    let entry = carts[path.row]
    deletItem(id: entry.meal_id)// call api to delete items
    carts.remove(at: (path as NSIndexPath).row);
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [path], with: .left);
    print("delete")

}
```

*UPDATE*

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if carts.isEmpty == true {

        proceedbtn.isHidden = true
    } else {
        if carts.isEmpty == false {
            if proceedbtn.isHidden == true {


            proceedbtn.isHidden = false
        }
    }
    }
```

get data :

```
func getData () {


    Alamofire.request(url!, method: .post, parameters: param,encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
        if let value: AnyObject = response.result.value as AnyObject? {
       // get data 

                 self.price = subJson["price"].stringValue
                 self.qty = subJson["qty"].stringValue
                 let id = subJson["id"].stringValue

              self.id = id
              self.name = subJson["meal"]["name"].stringValue


                let info = Cart(meal_id: self.id, qty: self.qty, meal_name: self.name, price: self.price)

                self.carts.append(info)
          }

        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }

}
```

Comment: can you show/ tell us the code that you use to add items in it?

Comment: check updated question please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable/Disable buttons based on the `cards` array count.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

       self.total.isHidden = carts.isEmpty
       self.proceedbtn.isHidden = carts.isEmpty
       self.totalLab.isHidden = carts.isEmpty

        if carts.count > 0 {
            self.tableView.backgroundView = nil
            self.tableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine
            return 1


        }

        let rect = CGRect(x: 0,
                          y: 0,
                          width: self.tableView.bounds.size.width,
                          height: self.tableView.bounds.size.height)
        let noDataLabel: UILabel = UILabel(frame: rect)

        noDataLabel.text = "nothing, the table is empty"
        noDataLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        noDataLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        self.tableView.backgroundView = noDataLabel
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = .none

        return 1
    }
```

**While delete a cell by sliding :**

You have to disable the button while delete the cells from cart table view, by checking the count of `carts` array

```
func deleteMail(_ path:IndexPath) {
    guard carts.count > path.row else {
        print("Index out of range")
        return
    }

    let entry = carts[path.row]
    deletItem(id: entry.meal_id)// call api to delete items
    carts.remove(at: (path as NSIndexPath).row);

      //You have to disable the button while delete the cells from cart table view
      if (carts.isEmpty) {
         self.total.isHidden = true
         self.proceedbtn.isHidden = true
         self.totalLab.isHidden = true
      }

    tableView.deleteRows(at: [path], with: .left);
    print("delete")

}
```

Comment: that works! thanks. how about when I access the view and the cart is already empty ? I tried to implement `if cart.isEmpty` in viewDidLoad but didn't work

Comment: When you are opening a view check the `carts.isEmpty`. And make sure you array has been allocated

Comment: tried but it hides buttons and labels even when carts isn't empty

Comment: When r u adding the item to card? Where you are allocating the `cards` array?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148437/discussion-between-subramanian-and-leo0019).

Comment: You have to check this inside the api completion block. If you check before that it will be empty always

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want something like a

```
func cartsDidUpdate() {
    let cartIsEmpty = carts.isEmpty
    total.isHidden = cartIsEmpty
    proceedbtn.isHidden = cartIsEmpty
    totalLab.isHidden = cartIsEmpty
    // Also any other UI-style logic based on cart being empty
}
```

which you could call where you have `print("delete")` and could also call from wherever you add new carts.

Comment: cart is empty and all the UI are not hidden

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I follow.
The logic I described uses the fact that your tableView's contents should be based on some global source. In your case that source is `carts`, right? Similarly, you want your buttons' appearance to be based on that same source. Rather than making your buttons check the number of cells in your table, you should have them be hidden or not based on whether or not `carts` is empty. Conveniently, Apple has supplied the `.isEmpty` function to give you that information.